# Loading images in collection view from documents folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a list of images in my resources folder that I want to load into a collection view

I have my images file names in an `NSAarray` from the documents directory.

.h

```
{
NSArray *fileList;
NSString * searchedImage;
}
```

.m

```
    NSFileManager *filesm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSArray *getFilelist= [filesm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];
    BOOL isDirectory;
    for (searchedImage in getFilelist){
        BOOL fileExistsAtPath = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:searchedImage isDirectory:&isDirectory];
        if (fileExistsAtPath) {
            if (isDirectory)
            {
                //Found Directory
            }
        }
        if ([[searchedImage pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {

            //This is Image File with .png Extension
            NSLog(@"directoryContents = %@",searchedImage);


        }
    }


    //count files
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *pathsAmount = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    fileList= [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[pathsAmount objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];
    int filesCount = [fileList count];
    NSLog(@"filesCount:%d", filesCount);


    UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];
    [self.appliancesCollectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];


  }
return self;
}
```

this reurns my image names correctly as `63293446.png`, `appliance63293447.png`, `appliance63293448.png`, `appliance63293449.png`,  etc in `viewDidLoad`

I want to load these into my collection view cells.  Currently it returns a null value for my images file names when in the `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

What ive tried so far in addtion to researching on here

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return fileList.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",searchedImage]]];
    NSLog(@"cell Bg image %@",searchedImage); <-----------------//returns null
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: This is confusing. You say that your array is 'searchedImage', then you use it as a string to create the image. You say you get valid names (I assume 'searchedImage' contains the filenames) and then you say it returns null. Can you clarify a little?

Comment: What is `searchedImage`? Are you saying that you are getting `cell Bg image null` in your log?

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that populates `searchedImage` and how its defined.

Comment: please paste you code where you are initializing the fileList, & searchedImage both.

Comment: Code updated, @ Akshat Yes

Comment: You need to learn about variable scope.  Both `getFilelist` and `searchedImage` go out of scope before you use them.  See (for example) http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]]];
```

make sure searchedImage is not nil.

Comment: Thnaks for answer, searchedImage is not nil thats returning correctly in viewDidLoad, still returns nill in `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Answer (score 0):

The file name of the image is in your `fileList` array, not in `searchedImage`, (this last variable is useless when creating the image).

```
NSString *fileName = [fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: fileName]];
```

The problem here is that in your code, fileList can contain files that are not images, thus `imageNamed:` will fail, and return nil. You should filter your fileList array, and make sure it contains only images.

Comment: What I dont undertand is why its filtered at ` if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"])` the as you say containing all the files from the documnets directory when I want to use it in `-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

Comment: Your array is not filtered. when you use `NSArray *getFilelist= [filesm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[paths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];` you have all the files (possibly including non images). The line `if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"])` is not having any effect on your code.

Comment: It is filtered at ` if ([[item pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"])`  as my log is returning only png files as required.

Comment: @JSA986 You're wrong... you are only PRINTING png files! Your code says "if it's a png file, print it on the log"... But the array can contain other files!!!!

Answer (score 0):

At first make fileList mutable via `NSMutableArray *fileList;`
next in block add image path to fileList

```
  if ([[searchedImage pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"png"]) {

       //This is Image File with .png Extension
        NSLog(@"directoryContents = %@",searchedImage);
        [fileList addObject:searchedImage]
   }
```

then in `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` set image with

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
```